# What is the best way to enumerate the properties of all USB devices attached to a Raspberry Pi 4B using C# .NET 7?

Tags: c#, .net, raspbian, raspberry-pi4

I am somewhat new to Linux (Raspbian 11). I am writing a C# .NET 7 application and need to obtain a list of USB devices attached to the Raspberry Pi 4B.

For each USB device attached, there is a zero-byte file in the `/dev/bus/usb/001` folder. As these files are of size 0 bytes, no information on the USB devices are stored in these files.

The `Microsoft.Windows.Compatibility` and `System.Management` do not seem to work for Raspbian 11.

My questions are:

1. How do the `lsusb` and `dmesg` commands obtain data on the USB Devices?
2. Do I need to create a process and pipe `lsusb` and `demsg` calls to the OS and parse the output?
3. Is there a NuGet package (`Device.Net.LibUsb` may be a possibility?) that can be used with .NET 7 to access USB devices?

Comment: Are you surprised that `Microsoft.Windows` libraries don't work in a different OS?

Comment: There is a note on Microsoft: ". NET is available in official package archives for various Linux distributions and packages.microsoft.com" from 10-Jan-2023. Since this project targets multiple operating systems, the use of .NET Core would be very convenient.

Comment: Sure, you can run .Net Core on a Rapsberry Pi (it's great!). But starting with Core they split out Windows-specific APIs from the main part of the BCL. It's those specific APIs I'm referring to.